# Creating my own Image Picker

Tags: ios, camera-roll

I'd like to create a custom image browser in my app that uses the images from the camera roll.

i.e. I'd like to completely replace UIImagePickerController and use my own control.

Is there a way of accessing the camera roll photos in this way?

Cluster App does this but I can't find a picture of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to access the images.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [QBImagePickerController](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePickerController) on the GitHub. They implemented custom image picker controller very similar to UIImagePickerController with added multiple selection feature. It will help you. Atleast look at this [file](https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePickerController/blob/master/QBImagePickerController/Classes/QBImagePickerController.m)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RengarViewController](https://github.com/peiweichen/RengarViewController)

a custom image picker controller which make use of Photo Framework (introduced in iOS 8).

It has nice UI, can be scrolled and panned.